# Save image in db from django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to save image in db from django model?
 I donot want to upload it in any folder , just want to save it in db from models.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to store binary data then Django (1.6 only) offers [`models.BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield).

It is important to note that the docs state:

> Although you might think about storing files in the database, consider
>   that it is bad design in 99% of the cases. This field is not a
>   replacement for proper static files handling.